# No muestra en pantalla los datos de mi tabla de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero mostrar en mi archivo php tomando de mi base de datos MySQL el CodigoCliente y el NombreCliente de mi tabla Clientes de mi Base de Datos 'jardineria', este es el código que tengo pero no se me muestra nada en el navegador. La conexión con la base de datos funciona correctamente ya que no me sale el mensaje de Error..  ¿Donde esta el error?

```
<?php

$conex=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jardineria");

if($conex->connect_errno){

  echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION BDD";
  exit();

}
else{



  $consulta="SELECT*from Clientes";
  $conex=mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);



  while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($conex, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

      echo $fila['CodigoCliente'];
      echo $fila['NombreCliente'];
  }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Y que te muestra???

Comment: nada.. página en blanco, la conexión con la base de datos funciona bien ya que si no me saldría el mensaje de error

Answer (score 1):

Realmente a tu código le faltan varios controles:

- Si la consulta falla
- Si no arroja filas

He agregado esos dos controles, y también uno a la conexión, aunque dices que funciona. De todos modos este es un código *estrictamente controlado*  que recoge en una variable `$msg` cualquier cosa que ocurra, mostrando finalmente en pantalla el resultado.

He comentado en el mismo código aquellas cosas que podrían ser nuevas para ti. He usado el estilo orientado a objetos en todo, es más moderno, más elegante, más claro, más intuitivo. Todo lo negativo está al final, en los `else`. No me parece que lo malo se deba poner nunca por delante :)

Espero te sea de utilidad:

```
<?php 
    /*Controlamos la validez de la conexión*/   
    if ( $conex = new mysqli("localhost","root","","jardineria") ){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM Clientes";
        /*Controlamos un posible fallo de la consulta*/
        if ( $result = $conex->query($sql) ) {
            /*Verificamos  cuántas filas trajo la consulta*/
            $totalFilas = $result->num_rows;    
            if($totalFilas>0){
                $msg=printf("Se encontraron %d filas.\n", $totalFilas);
                /*Usamos un método más específico*/
                while($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $msg.=$fila['CodigoCliente']." - ".$fila['NombreCliente'].PHP_EOL;
                }
            } else {
                $msg="No se encontraron registros";
            }
        } else {
            $msg=printf("Error en la consulta %s", $conex->error);
        }
    } else { 
        $msg="Error de conexión";
    }
    /*Imprimimos lo que recogió $msg*/
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No lo he probado, pero según los ejemplos que he hecho, así es como me han funcionado (dentro del < tbody> si es que esto es una función)**

```
< ?php
$conex=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jardineria");
if($conex->connect_errno){
  echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION BDD";
  exit();
}
else{
  $consulta="SELECT*from Clientes";
  $results=mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);

  while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
      echo '<tr><td>' .$fila['CodigoCliente'].'< /td>< 
td>'.$fila['NombreCliente'].'< /td>< /tr>;
  }
  }
? >
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que pudieras manejar tu código de la siguiente manera

```
$conex= new mysqli("localhost","root","","jardineria");

if($conex->connect_errno){
    return $conex->connect_error;
}
else{
    echo "Conectado";
}


$consulta= $conex->query("SELECT * FROM Clientes");

foreach($consulta as $dato)
{
    echo $dato["CodigoCliente"];
    echo $dato["NombreCliente"];
}
```

**EXPLICACIÓN DEL CÓDIGO**

1. declaro la conexión con `new mysqli`
2. Para obtener el error que se diera si no se conecta, hago `$conex->connect_error;`
3. Para ejecutar la consulta, como no recibes valores dinámicos por parte dle usuario, es de este modo `$conex->connect_error;`
4. con un bucle `foreach` hago el recorrido del dataset que me esta siendo devuelto y ya con la variable `$dato` accedo por el nombre de cada columna para imprimirla
5. Para poder ejecutar la consulta sería mejor que sea de este modo: `$consulta = $conexion->query("aqui el query.........");`